# Use puppeteer click link in angular app not working

Tags: angular, router, puppeteer

I'm trying to use puppeteer to test angular app. But it doesn't work when I try to click a link(not routing to corresponding view).

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.goto('https://example.com', {waitUntil: 'networkidle'});
await page.focus('input[name="username"]');
await page.type('username');
await page.focus('input[name="password"]');
await page.type('password');
await page.click('button[type="submit"]');
await page.waitForNavigation({waitUntil: 'networkidle'});

// code below logs https://example.com
// actual url is https://example.com/#home
console.log(page.url())

const link = await page.$('a[href="#/other"]');
await link.click()

// code below logs https://example.com 
// actual url is still https://example.com/#home
console.log(page.url())
```

After click link, it feels like a page refresh and goes to the same url again. `url` not changing is probably because `FrameNavigated` event is not dispatched from puppeteer. So how do I wait angular router finish and all corresponding ajax request end?

Answer (score 0):

Good day
Try to wait for navigation

```
await page.waitForNavigation(5);
```